# Como Restar Tiempo entre dos Tablas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy trabajando un sistema de eventos y quisiera saber como obtener el rango de tiempo disponible para agendar. Tengo la siguientes tablas

#### Tabla1 (Para registrar la disponibilidad de crear eventos)

```
| Fecha         | Hora Inicio   | Hora Final  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| ----------- |
| 2019-02-01    | 09:00:00      | 12:00:00    |
| 2019-02-01    | 13:00:00      | 17:00:00    |
```

y luego tengo la `Tabla2` para registrar propiamente los eventos, tomando en cuenta la disponibilidad en la `Tabla1`. La `Tabla2` y la `Tabla1` tiene los mismos campos. Un ejemplo de los registros de la Tabla2 serian los siguientes:

#### Tabla2

```
| Fecha         | Hora Inicio   | Hora Final  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| ----------- |
| 2019-02-01    | 08:00:00      | 11:00:00    |
| 2019-02-01    | 13:00:00      | 14:30:00    |
```

La pregunta en concreto es: **Cual seria la consulta SQL para poder determinar cuales son los rango de tiempo restantes, disponibles de la `Tabla1` con respecto a los que ya han sido tomados o apartados en la `Tabla2`.**

**Estoy usando Laravel pero no puedo conseguir la consulta SQL exacta que me funcione en este caso.**

Espero haber sido claro. Gracias de antemano.

---

*Segurencia de edición*

#### Vista objetivo

El objetivo final es mostrar la siguiente vista. En la que muestra los horarios disponibles, considerando los eventos que consumen parte del tiempo.

```
| Fecha         | Hora Inicio     | Hora Final  |
| ------------- |: -------------: | ----------- |
| 2019-02-01    | 08:00:00        | 09:00:00    |
| 2019-02-01    | 11:00:00        | 12:00:00    |
| 2019-02-01    | 14:30:00        | 17:00:00    |
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tendrías que crear una vista para tus tablas, y luego sacar las diferencias entres las horas transcurridas. o pruebas con este select. espero que te sirva

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF("07:30:00", "09:00:00");
```

Aquí tienes el [manual de referencia.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Comment: además la pregunta va a escribir la consulta a través de Eloquent en laravel

Comment: Ese SELECT sirve para Microsoft SQLServer, no.Los corchetes no van

Comment: exacto y el OP esta preguntando por MySQL